# Glass AlertDialog upsizing icon

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am following all the instruction from https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-design#alert

but the icon displaying in alert dialog is stretched and clipped as shown below:

[image: Alert dialog icon issue]

Please guide how to correct this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the exact code for the CardBuilder you're using and possibly a reference to the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your icon is in the `drawable-hdpi` folder of your `res` directory and not in the plain `drawable` folder or the folder for a different pixel density.